# Which servie is better for achieving SMS functionality in web application

Tags: php, sms, twilio, tropo, plivo

I am creating a web application which includes a module for sending message from the website.
I heard of some services which are used for achieving this purpose like:

1. TWILIO
2. TROPO
3. CLOCKWORK SMS
4. PLIVO
5. NEXMO

My purpose is, a user comes to the website and there is a contact form contains three fields:

```
Name
Mobile Number
Message.
```

The user enters his name, mobile number and message and then submits. I need to receive this message to my virtual number which I will get after creating an account in any of the above services. After I receive the SMS on my virtual number an automated reply need to be sent to the user's mobile number, the one he enters in the mobile number field of the form.

Is it possible to achieve this? If so which of the above services are better to achieve this functionality. Anyone help me out from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used both Plivo and Twilio. I chose to stuck with Twilio as we were encountering bugs with Plivo at the time, and their documentation wasn't as extensive as Twilio. Twilio can do all that you suggested and they have lots of tutorials and guides on how to do it.

Comment: Twilio is better then Plivo.